# How to fix AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter. at boot Void Linux

Tags: linux, boot, amd-graphics, void-linux, iommu

I am using an amd laptop.

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (8) @ 2.100GHz
- GPU: AMD ATI 03:00.0 Picasso

While starting void I get this message on top

```
AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter
```

I tried some other solutions on stackoverflow/reddit where you add something to grub config and then it gets fixed but for my specific graphics It isn't working Please Help.

I have tried adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"` and also tried adding `iommu=pt` to the end of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line in /etc/default/grub;

Comment: Welcome to U&L. It may help if you post exactly what you have tried so others won't suggest the same.

Comment: @bu5hman Thanks.. Done :D